# Generating random images in matlab

Tags: matlab, pattern-recognition, image-processing

I need to generate a fixed number images randomly from a file in matlab. For this do i need to  first convert the images into vectors or can i use a random function on the images directly?

So for example, i need 15*N images for testing, where lets say N=3. I have 165 images so 45 images will be my training set. Is there any built in matlab function to generate random images from a file?

Comment: What do you mean by generating an image from a file? Can you give an example of such image?

Comment: i have 165 images in a file. I know imread reads all the images from a file. But i want to know how to read those images (form - pmg) randomly so that i have only 45 images in my training set

Comment: What is the image file format?

Comment: How can you have `165 images in a file`? What magical file is it? Or do you mean a folder/directory?

Comment: OP may have a tif file containing multiple images. And he wants to get randomly selected images from the file. It took several minutes for me to understand his intention.

Comment: @Aksakal The image format is pgm.

Comment: @Divakar   i meant folder sorry

Comment: @user3344978, so is this a folder with a bunch of files containing images? I don't think anybody understands what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user3344978 Do all those images files in that one folder have the same image file extension?

Comment: @Divakar Yes and it pgm. Ok so to be more clear i have one main folder with 15 subfolders. each of those 15 subfolders has 11 images (.pgm). (15*11=165) I need to select, say, N number of images randomly from each subject such that N < 11. Which means for each experiment, i need to have 15N images as my training and rest for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want a random sample of images.

Use the randsample command from matlab to select random image indexes and then load those.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html